# How can I convert codon coordinates to genomic position?

Tags: gene, genome, phylogenetics, igv

I am looking for a given mutation in [IGV](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019796/uploads/FileUpload/c4/d9900bc2df5ef6ed48c9709bb16de9.png), which accepts coordinates in the form of

```
chr<X>:<Y>
```

Where X is the chromosome number and Y is the base location in that chromosome.

Eg. `chr6:26091179` which has the following attributes:

```
Gene: HFE|LOC108783645
Marker: rs1799945
Position: chr6:26091179
```

Additionally, an interval can be written like

```
chr<X>:<Y>-<Z>
```

So basically from base located at Y to Z.

**My questions are:**

**1)** How do I convert `HFE|LOC108783645` to `chr6:26091179` (and vice-versa)?

**2)** How do I convert `rs1799945` to `chr6:26091179` (and vice-versa)?

**3)** On a different example, how do I convert something like `codon 109 of exon 3 of beta globin gene (GTG->TTG)` to `chr<X>:<Y>` (or `chr<X>:<Y>-<Z>`)?

Why are there so many ways to specify positions in genes? For me the most clear way is `chr<X>:<Y>`, all the others leave me guessing...

Comment: You should look at HGVS conventions used to refer to positions with respect to reference sequences. Remember, not even `chr:pos` notations are independent of reference sequence versions. `chr6:26091179` in GRCh38 is not the same in GRCh37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `HFE|LOC108783645` is https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/108783645. You can use biomaRt to go from the `LOCxxxx` ID to location. Searching by `HFE` will give you a different location though, so you might have to account for such eventualities. It is a long and often manually intensive process.
2. You should be able to use entrez-direct/eutils to go from rsID to position
3. Unless there's some sort of natural language processing API, `codon 109 of exon 3 of beta globin gene` cannot be parsed by existing APIs (Unless it's always `codon X of exon Y of Z`, in which case you could use `grep` too get the components. Even so, going from exon + codon + codon base change to exact base location will require a lot of wrangling.